# Can we give the project path and executable dependencies from Master machine in Jenkins Integration?

Tags: java, jenkins, katalon-studio

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows

I have read the above link and implemented.

I came across two path:

```
1. Master and Slave both are same machines - Working Fine
2. Master and Slave Machine both are different 
Consider Master Machine: 3020721 and slave 3020722
```

Below are the windows batch command in Build section:
Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-5.3.0 and Project both placed in 307022 (Slave Machine)

```
cd C:\Users\3020722\Downloads\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-5.3.0
katalon.exe  -runMode=console -projectPath="C:\Users\3020722\Katalon_Studio\PoC\PoC.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/POCTestSuite" -browserType="IE"
```

Now If I wanted to use Katalon studio executables and Project from Master, I am trying below

```
cd C:\Users\3020721\Downloads\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-5.3.0
katalon.exe  -runMode=console -projectPath="C:\Users\3020721\Katalon_Studio\PoC\PoC.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/POCTestSuite" -browserType="IE"
```

It tries to `cd C:\Users\3020721\Downloads\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-5.3.0`  but says `the system can not find the specified path..`

Is it trying this path in the slave rather than taking it from Master?

Is this approach is possible?